# --disable -shared in gcc compiler

Tags: gcc, uclinux

I am new to this site.The compiler i have using is --disable -shared.but i need to create .so file.while creating .so file i am getting this error

error: no memory region specified for loadable section

How should i overcome this error.

```
root@coinel-PC:/home/coinel/Desktop/linux-cortexm-1.10.0# arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: arm-uclinuxeabi
Configured with: /scratch/julian/2010q1-release-uclinux-lite/src/gcc-4.4-2010q1/configure --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu --host=i686-pc-linux-gnu --target=arm-uclinuxeabi --enable-threads --disable-libmudflap --disable-libssp --disable-libstdcxx-pch --enable-extra-sgxxlite-multilibs --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-specs='%{O2:%{!fno-remove-local-statics: -fremove-local-statics}} %{O*:%{O|O0|O1|O2|Os:;:%{!fno-remove-local-statics: -fremove-local-statics}}}' --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-shared --disable-lto --with-pkgversion='Sourcery G++ Lite 2010q1-189' --with-bugurl=https://support.codesourcery.com/GNUToolchain/ --disable-nls --prefix=/opt/codesourcery --with-sysroot=/opt/codesourcery/arm-uclinuxeabi/libc --with-build-sysroot=/scratch/julian/2010q1-release-uclinux-lite/install/arm-uclinuxeabi/libc --with-gmp=/scratch/julian/2010q1-release-uclinux-lite/obj/host-libs-2010q1-189-arm-uclinuxeabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu/usr --with-mpfr=/scratch/julian/2010q1-release-uclinux-lite/obj/host-libs-2010q1-189-arm-uclinuxeabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu/usr --with-ppl=/scratch/julian/2010q1-release-uclinux-lite/obj/host-libs-2010q1-189-arm-uclinuxeabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu/usr --with-host-libstdcxx='-static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic,-lstdc++,-Bdynamic -lm' --with-cloog=/scratch/julian/2010q1-release-uclinux-lite/obj/host-libs-2010q1-189-arm-uclinuxeabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu/usr --disable-libgomp --enable-poison-system-directories --with-build-time-tools=/scratch/julian/2010q1-release-uclinux-lite/install/arm-uclinuxeabi/bin --with-build-time-tools=/scratch/julian/2010q1-release-uclinux-lite/install/arm-uclinuxeabi/bin
Thread model: single
gcc version 4.4.1 (Sourcery G++ Lite 2010q1-189) 
root@coinel-PC:/home/coinel/Desktop/linux-cortexm-1.10.0#
```

Comment: Build the compiler from source with -enable-shared.

Comment: Yes, as bmargulies says you would **at minimum** need to recompile the toolchain with shared library support. However, you may have to do more than that as well; supporting shared libraries on an MMU-less system is not necessarily trivial, and you may need to make some changes in your overall uClinux config as well. You likely need to do some research and reads the docs on your uClinux port before you dive into this

Answer (score 0):

Build the compiler from source with -enable-shared. – bmargulies